# Foreach loop returning null values in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

I have a pretty simple problem.

Basically I have an array called `$list` that is a list of titles.  If I do a `print_r($list)` I get these results:

```
Array ( [0] => Another New Title [1] => Awesome Movies and stuff [2] => Jascha's Title )
```

Now, I'm running a `foreach` loop to retrieve their values and format them in an `<ul>` like so...

```
function get_film_list(){
    global $categories;
    $list = $categories->get_film_list();
    if(count($list)==0){
        echo 'No films are in this category';
    }else{
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($list as $title){
           echo '<li>' . $title . '<li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is my loop is returning two values per value (is it the key value?)
The result of the preceding function looks like this:

- Another New Title
- 
- Awesome Movies and stuff
- 
- Jascha's Title
- 

I even tried:

```
foreach($list as $key => $title){
    echo '<li>' . $title . '<li>';
}
```

With the same results:

- Another New Title
- 
- Awesome Movies and stuff
- 
- Jascha's Title
- 

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You’re using `<li>` instead of `</li>` as closing tag. Use the proper closing tag and it should work:

```
echo '<li>' . $title . '</li>';
```