# Yet another simple php array looping newbie

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Sorry I am sure this is easy but I have spent ages trying to solve this simple problem. I have an array called `$listOfLinks`. When I `print_r` this is the output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [LinkID] => 1 [GroupID] => 1 [Description] => Home [Title] => Home Page [Hyperlink] => [Target] => ) [1] => Array ( [LinkID] => 2 [GroupID] => 1 [Description] => View Employees [Title] => View Employees [Hyperlink] => Views/ViewEmployees.php [Target] => ) )
```

I want to loop through the array printing out things such as the `Title`. So far my code looks like this:

```
foreach($listOfLinks as $key => $element)
{
    echo $key["Title"];
}
```

Something is wrong as the output is absolutely nothing. There is no error. message or anything. I have been trying to follow the advice on http://www.tizag.com/phpT/arrays.php but I seem to have misunderstood something.

This link to [Foreach loop returning null values in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483596/foreach-loop-returning-null-values-in-php) looked promising but it ultimately turned out to be a simple problem unrelated to mine. Also promising was [PHP: Loop through multidimensional array and establish parent-child relationships between array items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685825/php-loop-through-multidimensional-array-and-establish-parent-child-relationship) but it did not have a suitable solution. I thought I was close with this [Simple array question in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767700/simple-array-question-in-php) but it turned out to be unrelated. This also looked promising but wasn't. [PHP Yet another Multidimensional Associative Array problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029748/php-yet-another-multidimensional-associative-array-problem).

It looks like the answer is at [Another php array looping question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626602/another-php-array-looping-question) but I don't understand it if it is there.

Please don't hate me for such a simple question. I have really been trying really hard to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($listOfLinks as $value)
{
    echo $value["Title"];
}
```

What you are doing is indexing into the key. Instead index into the array element.

Answer (score 2):

When looping with the [**`foreach`**](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) syntax you used, you want to work with the `$element` variable *(which contains the current item's data)*, and not the `$key` one *(which only contains the index of the current item in the array)*:

```
foreach($listOfLinks as $key => $element)
{
    echo $element["Title"];
}
```

Also, as you are not using the key of each item, you can use this shorter syntax :

```
foreach($listOfLinks as $element)
{
    echo $element["Title"];
}
```

Comment: Great answer @Pascal but I have awarded the tick to xbonez because he answered first and does not have nearly the reputation you did. Your answer was equally good. Hope this is fair. Thanks.